# Personality Quirks of a Database

Tags: computers, psychology

I'm currently working on a world where there are people that live in data bases (basically a computer with no internet connection).  They link to a human for life and and can record everything the human experiences (this can be shut off by mutual consent of the human and the database for a period of time), as well as record all events that happen in the same room as them (kinda a sonar/radar effect).  They also have the ability to project an avatar and speak (these are independent e.g. they can speak without the avatar).  The size is variable, but is always easily transportable by the human.

Here is where it get fun.  They are unique individuals, much like humans. I wanted to avoid the "handwavium" of magic, but if it makes a difference, they are AI's built by magic to help casters recall spells in specific, but they also act as a perfect journal for that mage.  This allows them to be personalized to whoever they bond with.  But, a being with perfect memory and a want to help their human has a large chance of having personality quirks that are similar between individuals.  Unfortunately, I'm not a psychologist so I have no clue (and couldn't even begin to guess) what this would do to a human-like personality.

What manner of personality quirks would be likely to develop in a human that is a database [for storage and retrieval of data](and so has perfect memory)?

Comment: So what's the question? You may want to rephrase things, right now it sounds more like you're pitching a story idea then asking for help.

Comment: Sounds like you're going for a version of Sheldon from Big Bang, except in data storage format.

Comment: I agree with kuhl: I don't see a question here. I would point out, however, that a digital entity is unlikely to develop a human-like personality (though it could be programmed with one).

Comment: Read *Needle* by Hal Clement.

Comment: The question is: What manner of personality quirks would be likely to develop in a human that is a database (and so has perfect memory).

Comment: Note that these databases are built by humans for humans, so it is highly likely (in fact most likely) that they would have human-like qualities.

Comment: Bear in mind it sounds like you're asking for a realistic answer - but databases and data storage devices aren't really the same thing, the former is a system for retrieving data, and the latter is an actual physical item in which data can be stored - a hard drive. Also, things like hard drives don't have a processor, so anything on it would be a snapshot of a person/AI, not a running/living one.

Comment: Also, you're essentially asking for personality quirks an AI could have, and that depends on what type you're talking about. If the AI is completely and totally (essentially magically) sentient, then it could have any of the same personality quirks a human with good memory could have (excessive nagging being the first that comes to mind) but to a greater extent. But if its an AI in the realistic sense, that it's a program that someone coded themselves, then it could have whatever quirks that person programmed it to have - literally, absolutely, anything.

Comment: Your edit didn't really change anything, but I see you are trying. How about using the "question sandbox" to work in it with advise?

Comment: It seems a lot like what you are asking for is what quirks and personality would an 'archives' A.I. have. As it has been pointed out a database is very different conceptually from being capable of behavior (let alone thought) It's a bit like asking how a phonecall human would behave. (And not the phone). And if you are asking how the datastorage (or in my example the phone)-human would behave, well I get the picture of a harddrive with little arms and legs running around.

Comment: I finally understood thanks to feas' answer and the OP's comment in the answer. What you are looking for is bascially a magical database/archive-dude that lives magically in some part of your head, that catalogs everything that happens to you (your life) and that will help you, either by recalling whatever it is you need or with advice/suggestions based on everything you've experienced. The best example of this I can point to are the A.I.s in the Halo video game series, (the most popular example in modern day culture I believe would be the relationship between the Master Chief and Cortana)

Comment: @Spacemonkey, yes the relationship is similar to MC and Cortana (minus the whole romantic element, as most AI are the same gender as the human) in that the AI records information and helps recall it, specifically spell forms.  But the AI's data inputs are limited to the human and the room that it's data center is in.  (So I guess the AI isn't inside the person's head.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several classified types of memory recall. http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_memory

[Hyperthymesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_memory#Hyperthymesia) may be the best fit for you story as I understand it. 
People with this type of memory recall seem to be able recall every detail of a given day as if standing there in real time and describing what they see. As might be expected these individuals share some emotional characteristics of people with forms of autism.

Some other emotional characteristics that may be relevant to your story characters are what can manifest during hostage takings. 
The [Stockholm Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockholm_syndrome) is when hostages (your memory characters) begin to form an emotional attachment to their captors.
Reversely, the [Lima Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockholm_syndrome#Lima_syndrome) is when the abductor (people with memory module) feels empathy for the captive and lets them go.

Additional emotional characteristics that may develop from long periods of isolation for your memory character could include anxiety, hallucinations and lower mental performance to name a few.

[How Extreme Isolation Warps Minds (BBC)](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20140514-how-extreme-isolation-warps-minds)

Comment: After reading the first entry, the closer one is actually probably a mnemonic-type memory.  Stockholm syndrome is not a problem, as the data-people are almost symbiotic to the body-people, and so the relationship is basically that of really good friends.  The last link was *super* interesting, it gives me a basis for why the two don't just switch "data-share" off for long periods of time.

Answer (score 0):

Accumulating emotional overload.

"Time heals all wounds" is equivalent to "Forgetting heals all wounds." All emotions are connected to our memories and the fresher the memory, the stronger the emotion. For such a creature every event of their life feels like it happened a minute ago. Every joy, fear, hurt, disappointment, grudge, unless explicitly invalidated by a later event, remains with them at full strength.

You really need to develop some mechanism of coping with it, some kind of erasure spell or such, because the emotional load would become unbearable quite fast - especially with conflicting emotions when both good and bad things happen, although after any more stressful event they would suffer from a permanent PTSD attack.